# Microsoft Logging application block and multi-threading

Tags: logging

I am new to the Logging application block (4.1).
Has anyone written an application that uses the Logging application block from multiple threads? I am asking because the Logger is a static class and because of potential writing to the same log file from multiple threads for example.

Answer (score 3):

The Logging Application Block is thread safe, meaning you can call its public methods from multiple threads without doing any synchronization of your own. The library does its own synchronization.

Comment: I think what @Sunny is getting at is the problem when two instances of the application are running (e.g. a web application on a server), and they try to write to a log file at the same time, in which case the Enterprise Library will create a new log file and prepend a GUID to it, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure why you are concerned that this might happen. As long as you provide a category for your logging messages those should be written to the appropriate logging file configured for that category. This operation is thread safe.

Or are you talking about writing the logging messages of the same category to different files by thread? E.g. thread 1 -> mylog-1.log; thread 2 -> mylog-2.log