# A word that do so the ASP.NET (MVC) Routing crashes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I read about a string/word that did so the Routing crashed but I can't remember which word/string combination it was.

Example:

> [Microsoft Logging application block and multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685039/microsoft-logging-application-block-and-multi-threading) - works
>
> [Microsoft Logging application block and multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685039/hello) - works
>
> [Microsoft Logging application block and multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685039/random-random-hello) - works
>
> [Microsoft Logging application block and multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685039/banana) - crash!

No it's not banana, but it was a word/string that did so the the routing crashed in every app that used the routing system.

I think I remember this was a known issue but I can't remember where I can find it. Maybe I've read about it on stackoverflow in a comment.

Comment: con http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685039/con

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to TFD's answer ("con"), it looks like it's pretty much any of the MSDOS reserved device names (Listed under [Basic Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) on MSDN).

I get a HTTP 404 rather than an error though =)

Essentially the list from the extract below:

> Do not use the following reserved device names for the name of a file:
>
> > CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9

Comment: My memory said it was a 500 error but yes, it was only 404. Thanks for your description!

Comment: BTW, I suppose that if you turn off "exclude existing files" option, it will stop crashing.

Answer (score -4):

I dunno, but it sounds like Snow Crash, where if you just saw the image of the virus on your computer screen you would catch it and then you'd be doomed. I think it would be cool to be able to go around having sword fights in the Metaverse, so maybe it would be worth the risk.